# Function always returns same value

Tags: php, return-value

I created a function in PHP that searches for [profile|title] and creates URL for this profile...

```
function profileTagEplorer($message, $url) {

  $startLinkTag = '<a href="' . $url .'">';
  $endTag = '</a>';
  $res = preg_replace('#(\[profile\|)([a-zA-Z0-9áčďéěíňóřšťůúýžÁČĎÉĚÍŇÓŘŠŤŮÚÝŽ\s]*)(\])#', $startLinkTag . '$2' . $endTag,    $message);
  return $res;
}
```

Above in the code I have following cycle...

```
foreach ($owners as $owner) {

  // Prepare header
  $ep = new EmailPrinter();
  $ep->setReceiver($owner->email);
  $ep->setSubject($title);

  // Message 
  $message = profileTagEplorer($message, $owner->url);
  $ep->setText($message);
  $res = $ep->sendMail();
}
```

I've checked that $owner->url contains an unique URL for each iteration. However profileTagEplorer function returns always same result in every iteration, no matter that parameter is changing.

This same value is equal to URL from the first iteration of cycle.

Comment: I guess it's a problem with your regex. [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) returns the subject unchanged if no match was found. Have you tested your regular expression? (e.g. on [regex101](http://www.regex101.com))

Comment: treegarden you are right, I am an idiot! message is global variable so i replaced for first time and then as you said there was nothing to replace. Thanks